# How do you calculate the total count for all check boxes selected in your word document using the calculate on exit function?

Tags: checkbox, count, ms-word, cumulative-sum

I can't figure out how to get the total boxes selected when I enter them. It allows you to select calculate of exit but I can't figure out the correct code to enter into the properties location of a text form field to give me a count of all the ones checked.

Please help.

What I have tried in properties in text form field.

Type: Calculation  Expression: =SUM(COUNTIF(YES,TRUE)

I made all my checkboxes bookmarked as yes.

also tried: Expression: =SUM(COUNTIF(ABOVE,TRUE)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the value of the bookmark in a legacy (non-ActiveX) checkbox does not vary whether the box is checked or not. (I think it is always actually ""). So you cannot do the kind of calculation you describe without using VBA to inspect the checkbox value. Nor AFAIK is it possible to work around this by, for example, covering the checkbox with another bookmark and comparing that with a checked box in an IF field. It just doesn't work.

The traditional VBA-free solution is to use a DropDown field instead and test its value, for example use a DropDown with values Y or N and bookmark dropdown1 and use a nested field code such as `{ COMPARE { dropdown1 } = "Y" }` to get a 1/0 result. (Remember that al the { } have to be the special field code brace pairs that you can insert using ctrl-F9 on Windows Desktop Word.

Word's "field language" doesn't have a COUNTIF() function but you can for example use

```
{ ={ COMPARE { dropdown1 } = "Y" }+{ COMPARE { dropdown2 } = "Y" }+{ COMPARE { dropdown3 } = "Y" }
```

to determine how many of 3 such dropdowns are checked.